# redirect() function doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have create a web application using CodeIgniter making at first a login interface. Here are the controller I used but I think something doesn't work but I don't know what.The home page, where the user is granted, it doesn't show.Unfortunately I didn't have a debugger to check what doesn't work. maybe there is a problem to handle the session but really I don't know what can be. maybe you are smarther than me to find the error

---

### Login Controller

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User','user'); /* This call the model to retrieve data from db */
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(!file_exists('application/views/_login.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<h4 style="text-align:center;">','</h4>');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','trim|required|xss_clean|callback_pass_check');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            /* Data to pass to view */
            $data['title'] = "User Access";
            $data['author'] = "Salvatore Mazzarino";
            $data['year'] = date('Y');

            $this->load->view('templates/_header',$data);
            $this->load->view('_login',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/_footer',$data);
        }
        else 
        {   
            redirect('home', 'refresh');            
        }
    }

    public function pass_check($pass)
    {
        $result = $this->user->find_user($this->input->post('username'),$pass);

        if(!empty($result))
        {
            foreach ($result as $row) 
            {
                $session_array = array('id'=> $row->id, 'username'=> $row->username); /* Create a session passing user data */

                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_array);
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('pass_check',"Invalid username or password!</br>Try again, please!");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}

/* END OF FILE */
```

### Home Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        session_start();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {            
            $data['title'] = "Management Emergency";
            $data['author'] = "Salvatore Mazzarino";
            $data['year'] = date('Y');

            $this->load->view('templates/_header', $data);
            $this->load->view('_home',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/_footer',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        session_destroy();
        redirect('home','refresh');
    }
}

/* END OF FILE */
```

The model in the login controller works very well so It isn't a problem of query. Before adding session everything works but when I added session stopped to worked so I think that can be a problem or `redirect()` or session

### Home View

```
<div data-role = "page">

<div data-role = "header" data-position = "inline">
        <a href="" data-icon = "home" data-iconpos = "notext"></a>
            <?php echo heading($title,1) ?>
        <a href="" data-icon = "info" data-iconpos = "notext" data-transition= "flip"></a>
</div>

<div class = "menu-content">
        <ul data-role = "listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role = "list-divider">Emergency Menù</li>
                <li class = "menu-item">
                        <a href="">
                                <div class = "image-wrapper">
                                        <img src="/assets/images/user.png" class = "ui-li-icons" />
                                </div>
                                Add patient
                        </a>
                </li>
                <li class = "menu-item">
                        <a href="#">
                                <div class = "image-wrapper">
                                        <img src="/assets/images/home.png" class = "ui-li-icons" />
                                </div>
                                Show all hospital
                        </a>
                </li>
                <li class = "menu-item">
                        <a href="#">
                                <div class = "image-wrapper">
                                        <img src="/assets/images/favorite.png" class="ui-li-icons" />
                                </div>
                                Find patients
                        </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
                        <a href="#">
                                <div class = "image-wrapper">
                                        <img src="/assets/images/email.png" class="ui-li-icons" />
                                </div>
                                Send medical infos
                        </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
```

### Login View

```
<div data-role ="dialog">

<div data-role = "header" data-theme="e">
    <?php echo heading($title,1) ?>
</div>

<div data-role ="content">

    <?php 

        $var = validation_errors();

        if(!empty($var))
        {
            echo form_error('username');
            echo form_error('password');
        }
        else
        {                    
                echo heading('911 - First Aid',2,'style="text-align:center; color:red;"');

                echo form_open('login');
    ?>
                    <div data-role ="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="name" value="" placeholder="Username"/>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role ="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role ="fieldcontain">
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" data-theme ="b"/>
                    </div>

                </form>

   <?
        }
   ?>
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". We can't guess the solution *and* the problem.

Comment: @deceze Doesn't load home page...

Comment: Check your error logs. `Doesn't load home page` isn't an error message

Comment: I haven't any message in error logs otherwise I post it -.-

Comment: Is there are reason you are using PHP functions `session_start()` and `session_destroy()`? CodeIgniter doesn't use native PHP sessions opting rather to use cookies and/or database to store user data. I am not sure if this could cause problems, but if you aren't using them, I would suggest taking them out.

Comment: @wescrow I saw this way to do in the web. Anyway it's better to leave  out. but I don't think it is that the problem

Comment: Have you tried taking it out? I mean it is better to KNOW that it isn't the problem than to THINK that it isn't. Try that and rule it out. However, at a glance I can't see why that is the problem.

Comment: Put a `var_dump($this->session->userdata()); die();` at the beginning of the Home controller's index function. After logging in does the session userdata appear as you expect?

Comment: I eliminate session_start() and session_destroy and put var_dump() but nothing changed.when I log in I don't see anything.

Comment: So when you go to the Home page do you get redirected to the Login page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7646/discussion-between-mazzy-and-wescrow)

Comment: Wooooooo. That's a lot of code posted. ever heard of simplification. If you want people to answer you, don't  make your question too complicated to read. :)

Comment: When posting on SO, put some time into removing the irrelevant parts of your issue. There is a ton of code here. Take a backup and continually remove parts you feel aren't contributing to the problem.  Then post that code. As @deceze mentioned, we don't want to have to guess the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with CodeIgniter retaining it's session data after a redirect. Your `if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))` in your `home.php` controller will evaluate `false` every time because the session is resetting. You could use the native php sessions to skip over this problem.

See: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session/. Good luck!

**UPDATE**

Apparently, this is only true of CodeIgniter 1.7.2 when used with IE6. It doesn't affect most browsers.

Comment: So if the bugs have been fixed how is it possible I have that problem?

Comment: What browser are you using per chance?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome installed in Mac OS X Lion

Comment: Hmmm... That mustn't be it, if you are running 2.1. I'll look at it when I get back.

Comment: Yeah. So that doesn't seem to be the problem in 2.1. The only thing that I can think of is that there is something wrong with your Session library. Have you tried replacing the CI Session with the Native PHP Sessions yet? See if that fixes it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7702/discussion-between-mazzy-and-wescrow)

Comment: I wanna say you I RESOLVED the problem using the same CI_Session and we were so far away from the solution...the problem was the length of the user data field in mysql DB.instead to be 50 has to be more exactly 120 char

Comment: Awesome! That is great! I knew it was something with the database. Good job Mazzy!

Comment: I thought that the problem could be only the table...working on the table fixed the problem....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284918/using-jquery-mobile-and-codeigniter-framework-php

Answer (score 0):

open the **application/config/autoload.php** file and add the 'url' in the helper array;

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

i hope this will help you to fix the problem.