# using jquery mobile and codeigniter framework php

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I'm creating jquery mobile site using codeigniter framework.If I start my project without using jquery mobile in the head everything work but if I insert jquery mobile in the head of my page and try to start my project I receive a gray page with write on `undefined`. I want explicity say that I'm not using any scripts in my page only I call in the head :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
```

which are the scripts to use jquery mobile. Which could be the cause since I'm not expert in javascript

Comment: I can't recreate your problem, Mazzy. Could you please paste all of your code for your main page? Just go to the page, view page source, copy that, and post it. That will let us forgo the multiple files that MVC uses to create a simple page.

Comment: @wescrow where I load javascript in the head and try to login page showing me undefined gray page

Comment: @wescrow I didn't see the home page since the link remain in the login and show me only login code

Comment: @wescrow This is the scenary: 1. without jquery mobile scripts every works. 2. if I enable jquery mobile scripts and try to login, I receive an undefined gray page and the URL remain that of the login page but a session is create (in the table a row appears). If I manually insert the link of the home controller, the page is loaded correctly and I see the main page. SO I'm pretty sure it is a problem of javascript but I don't know anything of javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is an issue with noConflict?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

---

Update: it is an issue with data-url attribute used by jquery mobile. JQMobile uses that attribute to update the URL, so if it isn't set, redirects or other navigation won't update the url when using JQMobile.

---

Update to the update: the key was turning off ajax in the form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" data-ajax="false">
```

Comment: No clue then. Try editing your post and adding all the code from the page with the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7750/discussion-between-mazzy-and-stormdrain)